# Problema na instalação do yii2-braintree via composer

Tags: composer

Instalei o componente do Braintree, pelo composer, com sucesso. Agora, preciso de instalar um outro componente, o [yii2-braintree](https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-braintree).

Adicionei, como manda o tutorial, a linha `"bryglen/yii2-braintree": "*"` à secção `require` do meu **composer.json**.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "2.37.0",
    "bryglen/yii2-braintree": "*"
},
```

Depois, executei o comando `composer update` e o resultado foi:

```
sudo composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                                                                                                                            Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package bryglen/yii2-braintree could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Estou a fazer algo mal ou o problema é com o repositório?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema se dá devido ao [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) do composer.json, provavelmente está setado como @stable, e como a versão do pacote que está tentando clonar não foi especificada o composer tentará clonar a ultima versão que provavelmente não é compatível com o [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).

Para resolver este problema tente especificar a versão

```
"require": {
    "braintree/braintree_php": "2.37.0",
    "bryglen/yii2-braintree": "@dev"
},
```

[minimum-stability composer doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)